# Using .toggle() to show and hide a div on click not working

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to write a jQuery function to hide/show a div on a click.

I have an `<a>` tag  with the class `my-button`. A div with the class `my-div` is initially hidden with `display: none` when the page loads. When a user click on `my-button` and `my-div` is hidden, I want to show `my-div`. When `my-div` is visible, I want to be able to hide it when a user click anywhere on the page other than on `my-div`. This also includes a click on `my-button`.

```
<a class="my-button">Click me!</a>
<div class="my-div">Show Me or Hide Me!</div>
```

I tried to use the `.toggle()` function without any success; `my-div` won't show after a click on `my-button`. If I replace `.toggle()` by `.show()`, `my-div` will show and hide if I click anywhere on the page but not if I click again on `my-button`.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var $container = $(".my-div");

        $(".my-button").click(function(){
            $container.toggle();
        });

        if (!$container.is(e.target) && $container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $container.hide();
        } 
});
```

What would be the best way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var $container = $(".my-div");
  if (!$container.is(e.target) && !$(".my-button").is(e.target) && $container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $container.hide();
  }
});

$(".my-button").click(function() {
  $(".my-div").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="my-button">Click me!</button>
<div class="my-div">Show Me or Hide Me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must properly attached the event to the button and use `toggle()` to hide or show the `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".my-button").click(function(e){
      $(".my-div").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="my-button">Click me!</a>
<div class="my-div">Show Me or Hide Me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would try show/hiding just on the button click
Give this a try. First of all give your button an id="show_hide" and your div an id="my_div"

```
    $('#show_hide').click(function (e) {
        var x = document.getElementById('my_div');
        if (x.style.display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

You can change the ID's to whatever you want, but I suggest this in case you want to give other elements the same class but without this functionality

Alternatively you could add this to make it disappear when clicking anywhere else other than the button you should be able to use the following function

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    var x = document.getElementById('my_div');
    if( e.button == 1 ) { 
        var isHovered = $('#my_div').is(":hover");
        if (!isHovered) {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    } 

  }); 
});
```